# Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clr

I have been using Visual Studio 2008 quite long but lately I am getting this message when I am developing an application in C#:

> Common language runtime detected an invalid program

This happens when I try to enter to the properties of a component (text masked box properties, tool box property etc..). But it really became a problem when I tried to launch an other solution that I downloaded from the Developer's 5 star program of Microsoft and it didn't allowed me to launch at all and just got the same problem...

I looked for the answer at google but just got some clues about people having the same vague error but in different situations like in ASP.NET

I would appreciate any help with this issue... :( I do not want to reinstall VS, that will be my last resource...

**Update:**

I never figured out what the problem was so I installed a virtual machine with Windows XP on it, there I only have Visual Studio and Netbeans.

Comment: Check your Project References, that worked for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you reproduce the problem in a new solution without referencing any extra assemblies? If so, I think reinstalling would be your best bet. Sorry!

Comment: I tried the following:

1) Reinstalled the 3.5 .Net Framework // Didn't work
2) Reinstalled the Visual Studio 2008 Standard edition // Didn't work

:( ... still having the same ugly message: "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program" the problem is that there is no extra info that could give me a clue about the problem... 

Thx for the time

Comment: btw, I am getting this on Vista 32 bits SP 2 in a Core Quad... I do not know if this could help

Comment: FYI: I got the same message while messing around with Reflector + Reflexil. In my case the meaning was the I've destroyed the Dll somehow, and Visual Studio cannot use it anymore. so I guess that one (or more) of your important Dlls was destroyed...

Answer (score 9):

I faced this issue by trying to invoke System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
For this case the solution was to edit the project file and make sure the reference to related asembly looks exactly so:

```
<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />
```

Other ways to reference this assembly, via the VS 2012 asseblies picker and by picking the assembly into the physical location of reference assembly.

Answer (score 5):

I never did find a solution for this issue online. But what fixed it for me, was to use the 'Clean Solution' option in Visual Studio.

Seems VS had gotten a little 'dirty', somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Only you have to delete temparory asp.net files from

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

and then run your solution in asp.net.Now it will run properly.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this error. Peverify helped with finding the source - it was a method group invocation synthax. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Clean Solution" before going through Microsoft's troubleshooting guide.

Comment: Do you have a link to this?

Answer (score 1):

Could be the use of a referenced assembly that has a different CPU target of x86 or x64 to the one specified in the solution open in Visual Studio.

If you can recompile the assembly, set the target of the referenced assembly to the same cpu type as that of the open solution to fix this.

My circumstance was running on an x64 cpu with a target of x86 for my solution and a referenced assembly with a CPU target of Any.

Answer (score 1):

Well, (for me), I managed to fix this problem on my side after an hour of investigations.

In VB.NET (v4.0 VS-SP1), I found a bug where the compiler does not throw an error neither does the IntelliSense:

Notice below, if I add the following line in a function (anywhere in the program, Class / Module / Form / etc):

`MyGraphics.DrawImage(OriginalImage.Clone(New System.Drawing.Rectangle(ClipX1, ClipY1, ClipW, ClipH), Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb), 0, 0, TempWidth, TempHeight)`

The compiler throws this error before it even hits the function while debugging, it does not even reach the line (just adding to the functoin, causes the compiler to be scared of even entering this function).

I copied the line from another function in my code, the existing function works fine, however the new one doesn't. Which is quite shocking to be honest.

Now, I double-checked again and found the cause, as the `OriginalImage` object was defined as a `Bitmap` in the code that was working, however, I defined it as an `Image` in the one that did not work.

I further went to the code line above, and checked the parameters / arguments that the "clone" function above takes, the one from the `Bitmap` instance has the parameters correct and with 3 morphs (i.e. 3 different set of parameters you can call the function with), however, with the `Image` type instance, the `Clone` takes no parameters !.

I was quite shoekd to see this, the problem is that I didn't get any error nor warning in IntelliSense, nor compiler-error, the code compiled fine, but the function couldn't execute, I am sure this is a bug (Ahem... a Feature) in .NET.

Fixing it was to change the `system.drawing.Image` into `system.drawing.Bitmap`, code worked afterwards.

I hope this helps

Kind Regards
Heider

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after we installed AppDynamics. 
The solution was to uninstall AppDynamcis.

We are using .NET remoting, to call are web services. (Legacy project)

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine had a problem where his toolbox ended up corrupt. Try opening the toolbox, right-click, and choose 'Reset Toolbox'. You never know.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my machine solved this for me. It seems that there a lot of references to this problem that talk about a limitation of the size of a method and the number of local variables. This is only the case for .net framework 2.0 or less. So, your best bet is to Clean, Rebuild, Restart or in the end Re install the Visual Studio. In my experience it is more ofer a 'stuck/corrupt' Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of an old question but I just ran into this problem too.

For me it was simply that I was trying to use untyped objects instead of strongly type variables. I turned option strict on in my ASP.net project properties and fixed all the casting errors that popped up and it works perfectly now.

Something you may want to try before reinstalling VS or one of the other much more time consuming measures others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this totally bogus (or at the very least, misleading) error message by correctly using an object in the ADDHANDLER's HandlerObject parameter...I had put a class name in there by mistake!

Answer (score 0):

One more possible cause of this: I got this error when implementing Microsoft Fakes in unit testing. One of the .fakes xml files I was starting to manually set up looked like this before I added the namespaces I was going to generate for:

```
<StubGeneration>
  <Clear/>
</StubGeneration>
<ShimGeneration>
  <Clear/>
</ShimGeneration>
```

No tests were running and when I debugged tests in the project with this Fakes setup I got the *Common language runtime detected an invalid program* message. I took out one of the `<Clear/>`s and everything turned into magical rainbows and unicorns.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to remove optimizations and integer overflow checking.  Removing the trace and debug checkboxes on that same dialog box allowed it to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am using visual studio 2012 and have large level of project in vb.net. 
i also face this same problem in my pc during create columns in grid.

I just clean my project and ReBuild it then it is smooth to run.

Thanks you,