# Invalid Program Exception was Handled

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, exception

I am getting this error and Common Language Run time  detected an invalid program when i debug my application using F5. If i use CNTRL+F5 it is working fine why it is happening can any one tell.

Actually this one is coming only if i add DeployLX licensing which is a licensing software from XHEO.

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise it will be difficult to say anything about it...

Comment: Nothing there to post my code i just create a blank solution

Comment: Are you running on x64 Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The behavior you are experiencing is undoubtedly a consequence of your application being run with the debugger attached.** When you start your application using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, you are telling Visual Studio to "Start Without Debugging", as compared to just pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, which tells Visual Studio to "Start Debugging". The difference between the two commands is simply that the former does *not* attach the debugger to your code's process. Note that this is *not* the same as the difference between a Debug build and a Release build! Either build type can be run with or without the debugger attached.

Running your application without the debugger attached means a couple of different things:

- Breakpoints will not be hit
- Debugging symbols (your .PDB files) are not loaded, so you cannot step through the code
- Statements involving the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class will not be executed
- In C++, variables will not be initialized to their default values (but rather left as uninitialized)

In your case, I would guess that the exception you're seeing is being caught and handled somewhere higher up the stack from where it is thrown (presumably by some of the code provided by the DeployLX licensing stuff, although I don't know anything about this and have never used it) and therefore not shown unless you have the debugger attached. With the debugger attached, the exception is logged and displayed for informational purposes, regardless of whether or not it is handled appropriately.

You didn't explain exactly *where* this error is being displayed and how you are "getting" it. But if you'd like to customize the way exceptions are handled when the debugger is attached to the process running your code, open the "Debug" menu and click on the "Exceptions" option. From there, you can choose to break on all exceptions, even those that are handled, if you'd like to see what code is throwing the exception.

Comment: I am getting the exception some times and some time not i found that the exception is raising at this point  _license = SecureLicenseManager.Validate( this, null, info )

Comment: @Dorababu: Sounds to me like your license is not validating? Like I said, I honestly have never even heard of DeployLX licensing, so maybe someone else can help me out here. The best suggestion that I have is either to try fixing whatever is causing your license to fail validation, or contact the company who provided you the licensing code since that's clearly where the problem lies.

Comment: I contacted them he said that try to deploy it by using debug an cpu but the issue still remains same

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652630/clr-common-language-runtime-detected-an-invalid-program-in-vs-net), *Clean Solution* might be a good bet.

Comment: Cleaning the solution in the sense i have to recreate the application or should i reinstall the visual studio

Comment: In Visual Studio, if you right-click on the solution file in Solution Explorer, there is an option to "Clean Solution".

Comment: I tried that but it does not make sense still the issue is coming for me

Comment: The only way to resolve this is to contact the licensing vendor.